# how to fix get_result and fetch_assoc with bind_result and fetch(wtithout getting Null)?

Tags: php, api, null, mysqlnd

i'm working on a project base on a tutorial, looks like my host can't fully support mysqlnd for using get_result. so after i've did some researches, i've found solution in using bind_result, after hours i've tried to fix it and still nothing.

please help me to find the problem or change it in proper way.

Here are the Codes base on Tutorial which they worked fine with XAMPP :

Function.php

```
public function getUserInformation($phone)
{
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM User WHERE Phone=?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s",$phone);

    if($stmt->execute()) {
        $user = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
        $stmt->close();

        return $user;
    } else
        return NULL;
    }
```

And After I've changed them to this in function.php

```
public function getUserInformation($phone)
{
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT Phone, Name, Birthdate, Address FROM User WHERE Phone=?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s",$phone);

    if($stmt->execute()) {
        $stmt->bind_result($phone, $name, $birthdate, $address);
        $user = array();

        while($stmt->fetch()) {
            $tmp = array();
            $tmp["phone"] = $phone;
            $tmp["name"] = $name;
            $tmp["birthdate"] = $birthdate;
            $tmp['address'] = $address;
            array_push($user, $tmp);
        }


        $stmt->close();

        return $user;
    } else
        return NULL;
    }
```

and now i'm getting

```
{"phone":null,
"name":null,
"birthdate":null,
"address":null,
"avatarUrl":null
}
```

instead of

```
{"phone":"+18561523172",
"name":"Johb",
"birthdate":"1983-02-14",
"address":"Nxy 123",
"avatarUrl":""
}
```

thanks.

Edit 01.

to answer the questions about error, this is the error :

```
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: Phone in <b>/home/meskand1/public_html/pasargad-    drinkshop/getuser.php</b> on line <b>24</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: Name in <b>/home/meskand1/public_html/pasargad-    drinkshop/getuser.php</b> on line <b>25</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: Birthdate in <b>/home/meskand1/public_html/pasargad-drinkshop/getuser.php</b> on line <b>26</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: Address in <b>/home/meskand1/public_html/pasargad-drinkshop/getuser.php</b> on line <b>27</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: avatarUrl in <b>/home/meskand1/public_html/pasargad-drinkshop/getuser.php</b> on line <b>28</b><br />
{"phone":null,"name":null,"birthdate":null,"address":null,"avatarUrl":null}
```

before this with get_result i had issue with

```
Call to undefied method mysqli_stmt::get_result(
```

and the solution was to change it to bind_result and host don't care about mysqlnd problem

omg After almost hours i've fixed it by changin to this :

```
public function getUserInformation($phone)
{
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT Phone, Name, Birthdate, Address FROM user WHERE Phone=?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s",$phone);

    if($stmt->execute()) {
        $stmt->bind_result($arr['Phone'], $arr['Name'], $arr['Birthdate'], $arr['Address']);
        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
            $user[] = $arr;
        }
        $stmt->close();

        return $user;
    } else
        return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Why are you telling `bind_param()` that the value is an integer in the edited code? In your working code you set it as a string and it is a string as it starts with a `+`. Don't change the `$stmt->bind_param("s",$phone);` line.

Comment: Maybe if you add a bit of error checking you would see some errors

Comment: Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`
 to the top of your script. This will force any mysqli_ errors to generate an Exception that you can see on the browser and 
 other errors will also be visible on your browser.

Comment: You also bind to `$phone` and read `$id`

Comment: @jeroen man i'ts `s` not `i` i've changed, honestly i'm looking for this for a while, i've forgot to change things here, also $id changed to $phone

Comment: @NigelRen i'm sorry it was phone, i've forgot to change it here

Comment: @RiggsFolly Edited and u can see error now. everything was working great with get_result on localhost, but it just keep getting `Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result()` on on real host, and host admin just don't care.

Comment: Looks like you are going to have to change the code to use [`bind_result()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php). If the server does not have `mysqlind` installed there is no other option

Comment: @RiggsFolly man i've fixed it. Thanks for responds. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, then post an answer, so the question has some value to others that may find it

Comment: @RiggsFolly it's done. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution was to change the code to this. Thanks for Responds from [@jereon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/42139/jeroen), [@RiggsFolly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2310830/riggsfolly), [NiggelRen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1213708/nigel-ren).

```
public function getUserInformation($phone)
{
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT Phone, Name, Birthdate, Address FROM user WHERE Phone=?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s",$phone);

    if($stmt->execute()) {
        $stmt->bind_result($arr['Phone'], $arr['Name'], $arr['Birthdate'], $arr['Address']);
        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
            $user[] = $arr;
        }
        $stmt->close();

        return $user;
    } else
        return NULL;
}
```

Comment: for taking the time to post your own fix +1

Comment: @RiggsFolly thanks sir. actually i've was searching every method, after all it was one of the best experience i've had, bcs i searched everywhere, and nothing.